# dequeue script on mobile only using wp_is_mobile not working?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, elementor

Trying to dequeue some elementor scripts on mobile only AND woo product pages but when I use this it is dequeue on desktop and mobile, what am I missing?

```
function elementor_pro_frontend_scripts () { 
 if(!wp_is_mobile() || !is_singular('products')) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'share-buttons' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'share-buttons' );

    // Dequeue and deregister elementor-pro-frontend
    wp_dequeue_script( 'elementor-pro-frontend' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'elementor-pro-frontend' );

    // Re-register elementor-frontend without the dependency.
    $suffix = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min';
    wp_register_script(
            'elementor-pro-frontend',
            ELEMENTOR_PRO_URL . 'assets/js/frontend' . $suffix . '.js',
            [
                'elementor-frontend-modules',
            ],
            ELEMENTOR_VERSION,
            true
        );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the if statement.
!wp_is_mobile, you can read this as is not mobile.
||, is a OR statement not AND.
!is_singular('products'), is not a product page.
So try this:

```
function elementor_pro_frontend_scripts()
{
    if (wp_is_mobile() && is_singular('products')) {
        wp_dequeue_script('share-buttons');
        wp_deregister_script('share-buttons');

        // Dequeue and deregister elementor-pro-frontend
        wp_dequeue_script('elementor-pro-frontend');
        wp_deregister_script('elementor-pro-frontend');

        // Re-register elementor-frontend without the dependency.
        $suffix = (defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG) ? '' : '.min';
        wp_register_script(
            'elementor-pro-frontend',
            ELEMENTOR_PRO_URL . 'assets/js/frontend' . $suffix . '.js',
            [
                'elementor-frontend-modules',
            ],
            ELEMENTOR_VERSION,
            true
        );
    }
}
```